# Combo não exibe nome do Estado

Tags: cakephp

Olá. Através do bake, criei um formulário para incluir um Município. Entretanto, o bake ao gerar o formulário, exibe o id do estado e não o nome dele.
Como faço para que na como apareça o nome e não o id do Estado?
Se possível, gostaria de alterar a label de Uf para Estado e de nom municipio para município.

```html
<div class="municipios form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Município'); ?>
 <fieldset>
  <legend><?php echo __('Incluir Município'); ?></legend>
 <?php
  echo $this->Form->input('uf_id');
  echo $this->Form->input('nom_municipio');
 ?>
 </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Enviar')); ?>
</div>
```

O script utilizado para criação das tabelas Ufs e Municipios é:

```html
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ufs`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ufs` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo fornecido pelo IBFE',
  `nom_estado` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'nome do estado',
  `sigla` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'sigla do estado'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=0;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `municipios`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `municipios` (
  `id` varchar(7) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo do municipio fornecido pelo IBGE',
  `uf_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nom_municipio` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'nome do municipio'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=0;
```

Tela exibida:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O nome do label você pode incluir no segundo parâmetro, assim:

```
echo $this->Form->input('uf_id', array('label' => 'Estado'));
echo $this->Form->input('nom_municipio', array('label' => 'Município'));
```

E para o nome do estado, no seu model **Uf** é possível definir o atributo [`displayField`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#displayfield) que é o seu campo de exibição padrão:

```
class Uf extends AppModel {
    public $displayField = 'nom_estado';
}
```

Comment: Você é o cara, valeu...